# Spark dataframe aggregation with reference to another array column

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am having a performance related problem when aggregating a double array     by looking into index array.
What I mean by that is. original Dataframe looks something like this:

```
original Dataframe 

| id | prop1        | values                  |
|----|--------------|-------------------------|
|  1 | [2,5,1,3]    |   [ 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8] |
|  2 | [2,1]        |   [ 0.2, 0.3 ]          |
|  1 | [1,5]        |   [ 0.4, 0.3 ]          |
|  2 | [3,2]        |   [ 0.0, 0.1 ]          |

so in the column 2 which is prop1 is an int array having values within range of 1 to 5 but not in a order and there can be missing numbers within array.
```

Prop1 int array is like the index to the double array values
what i mean by that is row 1 looks something like below when exploded

```
| id | prop1 | values |
|----|-------|--------|
|  1 | 2     |   0.1  |
|  1 | 5     |   0.5  |
|  1 | 1     |   0.7  |
|  1 | 3     |   0.8  |
```

Final problem,

so I need to aggregate the values of double array by looking into index array and by column id

so outcome should be

```
| id | prop1          | values                   | 
|----|----------------|--------------------------| 
|  1 | [2,5,1,3]      |   [ 0.1, 0.8, 1.1, 0.8 ] | 
|  2 | [2,1,3]        |   [ 0.3, 0.3, 0.0 ]      | 


Below code I am using to extract the values by index and pivot right before merging them to array

//dummy dataframe to get the sequence of 5 but the upper end is dynamic value and that can extend till 300k
var df = (1 to 5).toDF("prop1")

//joining original Df by prop1 column 
var stgDf = originalDf.join(df,originalDf.col("prop1") ===  df.col("prop1"),"inner")

// pivoting the values by index
var pivotDf = stgDf.groupBy("id")
             .pivot("prop1").agg(first("values"))

 // now aggregating the pivoted  values by id
 var expr = pivtoDf.columns.map(sum(_))
 var pivotDf.groupBy("id").agg(expr.head,expr.tail:_*)

 //then grouping back into array by id
```

This solution I did using exploding the prop1 and value, it did work with few rows  but in the actual problem the arrays of both the columns can exceed 500k values each  and no. of rows per id can exceed 30million

If any one can look and help on this that would be great. application is build in scala using spark 2.4

thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the problem? 30m is nothing. Its big data.

Comment: Show your code as well

Comment: @thebluephantom please check the edited post with the code. The problem is how to aggregate the values of double array by index which is an array by column id. and 30m is per id and dataframe may exists of 1000s of ids. Please check the edited post and see if you can help on it. Thanks

Comment: Ok that is big data. I will look later

Comment: Still needing help?

Comment: yes @thebluephantom

Comment: Can you do a printSchema of the original DF pls?

Comment: it is int,Array[int],Array[Double]

Comment: No structs. Ok ..

Comment: Working on it..

Comment: Nearly there. On hols so will finish off tonight.

Comment: Only thing is I am looking at higher order functions using Spark 3.x. E.g. zip_with. That is also 2.4 as well I think.

Comment: No its not. Will work out 3.x and you will have to adapt to 2.4

Comment: I did this in between holiday activities. It is v3.

Comment: Did u look at the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For v3.x, not v2.4. Upgrade, as too difficult.

Some serious data wrangling!

There are probably better ways, but it is scalable. May need many partitions.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val arrayStructureData = Seq(
Row(1,List(2,5,1,3),List(0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8)),
Row(2,List(2,1),List(0.2, 0.3)),
Row(1,List(1,5),List(0.4, 0.3)),
Row(2,List(3,2),List(0.0, 0.1)) 
)
// Just a single StructType for the Row
val arrayStructureSchema = new StructType()
    .add("id",IntegerType)
    .add("prop1", ArrayType(IntegerType))
    .add("values", ArrayType(DoubleType))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arrayStructureData),arrayStructureSchema)
df.printSchema()
df.show()

val df2 = df.withColumn(
  "jCols",
  zip_with(
    col("prop1"),
    col("values"),
      // Should be a struct really, but...array used. zip_with not available in v2.4!
      (left: Column, right: Column) => array(left, right)
  )
).drop('prop1).drop('values)

df2.show(false)
df2.printSchema()

val df3 = df2.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("jCols").as("jCols"))
df3.printSchema()
df3.show(false)

val df4 = df3.select($"id",flatten($"jCols").as("jCols"))
df4.show(false)
df4.printSchema()

val df5 = df4.withColumn("ExjCols", explode($"jCols")).drop("jCols")
df5.show(false)
df5.printSchema()

val df6 = df5.select(col("id"),col("ExjCols")(0).as("prop1"),col("ExjCols")(1).as("values"))
df6.show(false)
df6.printSchema()

val df7 = df6.groupBy("id", "prop1").sum("values").toDF("id","prop1","values") 
df7.show(false)
df7.printSchema()

val df8 = df7.withColumn("combined", array($"prop1", $"values"))
df8.show(false)
df8.printSchema()

val df9 = df8.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("combined").as("propN"))
df9.show(false)
df9.printSchema()

val res = df9.withColumn("prop1",expr("transform(propN, x -> x[0])")).withColumn("values",expr("transform(propN, x -> x[1])")).drop('propN)
res.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+---+--------------------+-------------------------------+
|id |prop1               |values                         |
+---+--------------------+-------------------------------+
|1  |[2.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0]|[0.1, 0.8, 1.1, 0.8]           |
|2  |[2.0, 1.0, 3.0]     |[0.30000000000000004, 0.3, 0.0]|
+---+--------------------+-------------------------------+
```

No idea why the accuracy 0.3000... occurred, but it did. Also corrected the example, it had some errors.

I can only assume SO is less popular now as it took a while for an answer.